# Can a class that is a Spring Bean also implement Runnable

Tags: spring, multithreading, thread-safety

For the first time, I am writing an app that manually creates a new thread. I am creating and using the thread like so:

```
@Service
public class MyAppService
{
        myThread = new Thread(runnableThreadImpl);
        myThread.start();
}
```

runnableThreadImpl is an instance of:

```
public class RunnableThreadImpl implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        myProcessor.start()
    }
}
```

myProcessor is an instance of:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class MyProcessor
{   
    ...
}
```

My boss would like me to combine RunnableThreadImpl and MyProcessor into one class that would look something like:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class MyProcessor implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is: Are there any problems with having a Spring Bean implement Runnable?
Thx!

Comment: Why would that be a problem? Have you tried it.

Comment: @Deinum- There have been no problems so far, but how annotations work is largely a mystery to me and this is my first time using Runnable. So, I have no idea if they conflict with each other. And, it is my understanding that thread issues can be hard to detect/test for. I am hoping that somebody more experienced can give a definitive answer.